# C++: Whenever I try to view my array the first two inputs dont appear

Tags: c++, arrays

Instead of the first two inputs it begins at the third. this causes my entire array to shift two positions over and in the last two positions show really small numbers like 1.54831e-315.  this is my first submission so i apologize if i messed up somewhere.  Here is everything i wrote

```
const int ROWS = 3;  
const int COLS = 7;

double inputFood();  
void printFood();  
void avgFood();  
void leastFood();  
void largestFood();

int main()
{

    string day;
    double monkeys[ROWS][COLS];
    double avg, sum = 0, largest = monkeys[0][0], least = monkeys[0][0];

    inputFood();
    printFood();
    avgFood();
    leastFood();
    largestFood();



    return 0;
}

double inputFood()  
{
    string day;
    double monkeys[ROWS][COLS];

    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {
            switch(c)
            {
                case 0: day = "Sun";
                    break;
                case 1: day = "Mon";
                    break;
                case 2: day = "Tue";
                    break;
                case 3: day = "Wed";
                    break;
                case 4: day = "Thu";
                    break;
                case 5: day = "Fri";
                    break;
                case 6: day = "Sat";
                    break;
                default: cout << "No corresponding day. " << endl;
            }

            cout << "Enter pounds of food eaten by monkey " << r + 1 << " on " 
                 << day << ": " << endl;
            cin >> monkeys[r][c];   

            if (monkeys[r][c] < 0)
            {
                cout << "A monkey cannot eat a negative amount of food. " << endl;
                cout << "Enter the correct pounds of food eaten by monkey " << r + 1
                     << " on " << day << ": " << endl;
                cin >> monkeys[r][c];
            }

        }
    }
}

void printFood()  
{
    double monkeys[ROWS][COLS];

    cout << "Monkey\tSun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        cout << "     " << r + 1;
        for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
        {
            cout <<"\t" << monkeys[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
double inputFood()  
{
    string day;
    double monkeys[ROWS][COLS];
```

You have refefined an array inside the function and this array disppears after the function terminates. The array in the main function remains intact.

The function `inputFood` should take `monkey` as an argument.

In C or C++ the variables are not initialized by zero and they keep their previous value from memory. If you faced with crazy numbers such as `x10^-315` consider the variable has not been initialized by you.

**Update**

pass `monkeys` to `inputFood` in the main function:

```
inputFood(monkeys);
```

and change:

```
double inputFood()  
{
    string day;
    double monkeys[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    ....
```

into:

```
double inputFood(double monkeys[ROWS][COLS])
{
    string day;
    // remove monkeys here
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    ....
```

Comment: Sorry if this i seem clueless right now, but how exactly would I do that.  Two dimensional arrays are kinda confusing to me.